# Spring Boot - Load application.properties/yml from dependent jar

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring Boot application where I would like to inject values into a @ConfigurationProperties bean in a specific order.

For example,

`@ConfigurationProperties("myproperties")
class MyProperties {
  private String property1;
  ....
}`

### base-application.yml

`myproperties:
   property1: some-value`

The above class and properties file is in a jar file. In the mail application of my Spring Boot app (which has the above jar as dependency) I used `@PropertySource(value = { "application.yml", "base-application.yml"})` 
but got `null` values in `MyProperties`.

I tried

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.yml"),
    @PropertySource("classpath*:base-application.yml")

})
```

as well, but that didn't work either.

If I add the myproperties.property1 value in application.yml then it works fine. Is it possible to inject property values from a property file which is inside of another jar? If so, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> YAML files can’t be loaded via the @PropertySource annotation. So in
>   the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use a
>   properties file.
>   [Check the docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings)

Comment: That was good to know. However, after changing the yml in the jar to .properties file, it throws a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: you might wanna get rid of the asterisk after the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

if property files are in META-INF directory of jar, you can load of them as follows:
"classpath*:/META-INF/*.properties"