# how to have repeated configurations in springboot as jar and use as dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-kafka

We have many microservices for multiple tasks and most of them have some common functionality like log configuration, metrics configuration and kafka configuration etc.
We are planning to have a common JAR with common functionalities and utilise in all microservices.

When we created custom springboot jar with `application.yml` having these common configuration and few other @Component and @Service classes and included as dependency in microservices it's not reading any property from JAR specific `application.yml` inside the JAR.

Custom springboot jar -

```
src/main/java - 

    @Configuration
    public class KafkaConfiguration {}
    
    @Service
    public class CommonProcessor {}
```

src/main/resources -

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    org.apache: DEBUG
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          autoCreateTopics: false
          brokers: localhost:9092
          configuration:
            sasl:
              jaas:
                config: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="" password="";
```

In `KafkaConfiguration.java` I am reading above properties and creating kafka connection, kafka template object etc. and if I write sample consumer/producer inside this jar and run as springboot project everything works fine.

Bu I want to use this jar as dependency in my microservice and utilise the kafka connections/kafkatemplate etc. i.e when it is unable to load any properties from above `application.yml` and fails creating bean.

Microservice structure -

*src/main/java*

```
@Component
public class Consumer {
@Autowired
KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate;
}
```

*src/main/resources*

**application.yml**

```
test:
 property: test
example:
 service:
  url: https://localhost:8080/service
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>common-jar</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
```

What am I missing here because of which my JAR file fails to create the beans defined inside it by loading the properties? Is this approach of having 2 application.yml not correct? what is best way to have common properties in one place?

Comment: Are the package names same?

Comment: @springenthusiast you can give try
1. `@Import(CommonProjectConfig.class)`
2. `@ComponentScan("common project package")`
3. Suggest you to keep different properties file name like common.properties|yaml so that we can override in other projects
`--spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/common.properties`

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question**

If the dependency has a different package name, then use `@ComponentScan` like below to load any beans from another package.

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test.dependency")`

You can also declare beans programmatically in your main application.

**For second question**

There are many ways to do this. You can

1. Import the property source (using @Import)
2. Have an auto configuration annotation (Have a look at this [AutoConfiguration example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718763/how-to-inherit-application-properties-in-spring))
3. Have defaults loaded from the properties using classpath resolution. (See the same SO on how the application.properties was read)

**For question 3:**

IMO, the dependency must allow override properties from the main application. As defaults, you can keep the values in the dependency, but whether it is the default ones to pick up must be dictated by the main application. This approach can be seen in many other sdks and even spring modules itself.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I had to add componentscan both inside JAR and client project to get autowiring working, not sure why it's not working if I remove it from JAR. On the 2nd point, I changed yml file to different name and loaded using EnvironmentPostProcessor approach, but the kafka-consumer using kafka-binder approach is not able to find some of properties in client project, but other properties like logging.level, metrics are all getting loaded properly. Any idea whether kafka-binder approach doesn't support this type of loading?